# Copy NULL in PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to copy a CSV file into Postgres 9.5.3 and running into issues with NULL. The file is encoded in ASCII, my client_encoding is UTF-8, and server encoding is UTF-8. 
The null is in a quoted string as shown below.

[image]

I get this error

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
CONTEXT:  COPY test_null, line 1
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY test_null, line 1
```

My table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_NULL(NULLCOLUMN CHAR(10));

copy TEST_NULL from 'F:\User Area\DCS.TXT' csv  NULL AS 'null';
```

I have tried escaping it by specifying "\", and tried other options of Copy command, but nothing seems to work. Not sure, how to process this.

Comment: what is in line 1 of the `DCS.TXT` file?

Comment: You're confusing database nulls with utf8 encoding nulls etc. You need to get rid of the nulls in your text file. tr can do that, as can a few other utils. tr -d '\000' <infile >outfile

Comment: Can I redefine my column to bytea and load the NULL as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains ASCII 0 characters, which are rejected by PostgreSQL.

You'll have to use some other representation for NULL values if you want to load them into the database with `COPY`.